# Rails 4 jQuery truncate string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

want to implement (...) when the length for a text is superior than 150 character for example and this is my jQuery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("#content p").each(function(){
    if ($(this).text().length > 150) {
      $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 145));
      $(this).append('...');
    }
  });
});
```

this is my view

```
<div id="content">
  <p><%= job.job_description.html_safe %></p>
</div>
```

but the problem is this jQuery code work just for the first job_description why?

Comment: Is there an particular reason you want to use jQuery rather than a ruby helper method?

Comment: i don't know if this is happen just for me , when I use the ruby helper method it work but when hover the text it move i don't know why?

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite understand what you mean. As in you wrote a helper and it truncates your text but when you hover over it, it shows the entire text block?

Comment: non when hover my text it will change the margin-left dynamically like this -50px -40px .... 0px ... so you can simulate the move of the text

Comment: how can i turn html_safe with ruby helper method because if use this code  <%= truncate(job.job_description, length: 150) %> it will not turn html_safe

Comment: From the documentation: "The result is marked as HTML-safe, but it is escaped by default, unless :escape is false. Care should be taken if text contains HTML tags or entities, because truncation may produce invalid HTML (such as unbalanced or incomplete tags)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code to turn html_safe if you use a text editor like tinymce

```
   <div class="content">
     <p><%= truncate(job.job_description, length: 170, escape: false).html_safe %></p>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using ruby for this, you could use the [truncate method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate).

You could try this instead:

```
truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away")
# => "Once upon a time in a world..."

truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away", length: 17)
# => "Once upon a ti..."

truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away", length: 17, separator: ' ')
# => "Once upon a..."

truncate("And they found that many people were sleeping better.", length: 25, omission: '... (continued)')
# => "And they f... (continued)"

truncate("<p>Once upon a time in a world far far away</p>")
# => "&lt;p&gt;Once upon a time in a wo..."

truncate("<p>Once upon a time in a world far far away</p>", escape: false)
# => "<p>Once upon a time in a wo..."

truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away") { link_to "Continue", "#" }
# => "Once upon a time in a wo...<a href="#">Continue</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason why only the "first" works in javascript in a case similar to yours, where you're using element's `id` in DOM query is because there are multiple DOM elements with same `id` value.  You need to ensure that each element in a DOM has unique `id`, this is required for a DOM document to be valid.

When an `id` selector is used, the first element with the `id` is returned regardless of the number of elements with the same `id` in the document.  Of course, at least one element with the `id` has to be present in the DOM, otherwise the selector is not going to find anything.

So as a solution you could use html `class` attribute with same value for these elements.  Unlike `id`, `class` can be reused.

Something like follows:

```
# In your view
<div class="content">
  <p><%= job.job_description.html_safe %></p>
</div>


# JQuery
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(".content p").each(function(){
    if ($(this).text().length > 150) {
      $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 145));
      $(this).append('...');
    }
  });
});
```

Another approach as already mentioned by @8bithero, you could use Rails [`TextHelper#truncate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate) to generate the truncated text and not bother about javascript manipulation at all.  With this approach, you can get rid of the javascript code and update your `view` as:

```
# In your view
<div class="content">
  <p><%= truncate(job.job_description, length: 150) %></p>
</div>
```

Comment: how can i turn html_safe with ruby helper method because if use this code it will not turn html_safe

Comment: @user3330161, Please take a look at [`TextHelper#truncate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate).